# Searching Drive Folder from Apps Script with date query

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm having a problem in apps-script DriveApp.Folder searching for folders with a query string that includes a date.

```
var q = ("modifiedTime > \'"+Utilities.formatDate(fromDate, "CET", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'+01:00'")+"\'"),
   newFolders = parentFolder.searchFolders(q);
console.log("Q: "+q);
while(newFolders.hasNext()){
```

I get this in the log:

> E  RUNTIME error: [Invalid argument: q]
>       at dailyReport(Code:12) (STW Uploads) 0d8a194c-411c-4f06-aa82-d5e40c8550e5
>
> D  Q: createdTime > '2017-03-21T00:00:00+01:00'

The strange thing is that if I run the same query in the Drive API Explorer it works correctly.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: @Cooper I tried that with the same result

Comment: I went to this [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters) and there doesn't seem to be "created time" on that list.

Comment: That's true but modifiedTime is on there and I tried that with the same result. I'll change my example to use modifiedTime. I see that API Explorer is using v3 of the api while apps script is using v2. That could explain why my query works in the API Explorer.

Comment: Yup DriveApp is V2. I put together a Drive v3 library for Apps Script: https://github.com/Spencer-Easton/Apps-Script-Drive-v3-Library

Comment: So here's what caught me: v2 uses modifiedDate and v3 uses modifiedTime and createdTime. I was trying to use modifiedTime instead of modifiedDate with v2. I will check out your v3 library thanks Spencer-Easton.

Comment: Wow that's good to know.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

## Read the Fine Print

From Spencer Easton: Drive App is version 2
From kpg: version 2 uses modifiedDate and version 3 uses modifiedTime and createdTime. Drive API Explorer is version 3